# Is there a way to represent this function analitically?

Tags: integration, expected-value, approximation

I'm not good at this kind of topics, but I'm trying to solve a problem for the theory of probabilities - I need to find a continuous PDF, which limit at $+\infty$ doesn't exist - so I came across this function, which is represented graphically.

Here's [image: its graph]

Its integral is equal to 1. It's supposed to be a probability density function. I need to know the expected value (or the mean) for it:  $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_{\xi}(x)dx$.
I don't have to actually perform any calculations, but I must prove that it's possible, or, in other words, that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|x|f_{\xi}(x)dx < \infty$

How do I go about that? Is there any way to approximate this function analitically? (but its integral must be 1 in any case). I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Each area near $x = n$ is $2^{-n-1}$, and there $|x|\le n+1$. Hence $|x|f_\xi(x)\le (n+1)2^{-n-1}$, and their sum converges.

Comment: @Riemann thank you a lot! Seems like exactly what I need